# JQuery event won't execute - can't find syntax failure

Tags: jquery

a simple jquery event question i can't find my code failure. myid2 won't show up when mouse enters the myid-div. what's wrong with my code?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden { display: none; }
        .visible { display: inherit; }
    </style>
    <script class="jsbin" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#myid").bind("mouseenter", function(e){
            $("#myid2").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
        }); 
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myid">Mouseover-Text</div>
    <div id="myid2" class="hidden">Hidden-Text</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you want with your code

Comment: as per your code after mouse enter show #myid2, show it's work fine

Comment: See jQuery's `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Why are you using [a method](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) that was replaced in Nov 2011 with jQuery 1.7 and completely deprecated in 3.0?

Comment: I used the method, because i didn't know about the deprication of the bind method :) thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you're missing is  `$(document).ready(function(){`

Please replace this code with yours and it will work, here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myid").bind("mouseenter", function(e){
        $("#myid2").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to put the javascript at the end of the page. The elements you try to bind events to don't exist when your script is run and therefore the event is not activated. This should work (It will also work without the document.ready, but this is safest:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .hidden { display: none; }
            .visible { display: inherit; }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="myid">Mouseover-Text</div>
        <div id="myid2" class="hidden">Hidden-Text</div>
        <script class="jsbin" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $( document ).ready(function() {
            $("#myid").bind("mouseenter", function(e){      
                $("#myid2").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
            }); 
        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
  $("#myid").bind("mouseenter", function(e){
            $("#myid2").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
        });
```

```css
   .hidden { display: none; }
        .visible { display: inherit; }
```

```html
  <div id="myid">Mouseover-Text</div>
    <div id="myid2" class="hidden">Hidden-Text</div>
 <script class="jsbin" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `$(document).ready(function(){` 
At The Top of your Block Code